# 'Fata Error ' : Python executable throwing error

Tags: python-3.x, file, tkinter, exe, autopy

I have a '**working**' Python code, `TCP_Barcode_V1.py` which read a text file and gives output in a `tkinter` window.

However, if I convert the Python file to an .exe using `auto-py-to-exe`, when executing TCP_Barcode_V1.exe, am getting error like fatal error occurred **Failed to execute script TCP_Barcode_V1** in a messagebox

[image: error]

my text file, **param.txt** looks like this :

```
192.1.22.43
6666
3000
```

each line is read and stored in a variable

In my python file, am reading the file as

```
THIS_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
my_file = os.path.join(THIS_FOLDER, 'param.txt')

with open(my_file, "r") as fp:
  val = [line.strip() for line in fp]


duration = int(val[0])
TCP_IP = val[1]
TCP_PORT = int(val[2])
```

Can someone identify what the problem here is.

**Please note that the original TCP_Barcode_V1.py is working without any issues.  And also, I am using the same device for running the .py as well as .exe file.**

below is my `auto-py-to-exe` settings I chose

[image: AutoPy]

Comment: Can you run it with --debug flag?

Comment: @SaatvikRamani : Its showing file not found error but its looking at a different path. "..\\Appdata\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI78002\\param.txt. _MEI78002 is a temp folder, it changes everytime I run the application

Comment: You can specify the resources your executable needs using the `--add-data` flag. `pyinstaller --add-data "<PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE>" --noconfirm --onefile --windowed ""` You can also specify multiple files separated by a `;`.

Comment: Ok, what if I have to move the exe along with the text file to a different location? Does that mean I have to reconfigure the exe again?

Comment: Ideally, it should be in the same directory as your python files and hence is wrapped into your executable.